# Windows 10 Still Being Reported as 8.1, Even with Manifest File?

Tags: c#, vb.net, version, manifest

So I've done my due diligence first, and read as many SO issues as I found on this issue, and tried doing as they suggested; I still get 6.2 (Win 8.1) when calling these:

```
Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
```

**I've added the manifest file** (*here's the current version*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />      
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
           is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
           automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

      <!-- Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />

      <!-- Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

      <!-- Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

      <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

      <!-- Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

    </application>
  </compatibility>

  <!-- Indicates that the application is DPI-aware and will not be automatically scaled by Windows at higher
       DPIs. Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) applications are automatically DPI-aware and do not need 
       to opt in. Windows Forms applications targeting .NET Framework 4.6 that opt into this setting, should 
       also set the 'EnableWindowsFormsHighDpiAutoResizing' setting to 'true' in their app.config. -->

  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>

  <!-- Enable themes for Windows common controls and dialogs (Windows XP and later) -->
  <!--
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity
          type="win32"
          name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
          version="6.0.0.0"
          processorArchitecture="*"
          publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
          language="*"
        />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  -->

</assembly>
```

**Second question:**
When I uncomment the Win 10 line in the manifest, do I need to also uncomment Win7/8/8.1 as well? Or since those particular OS's are 'mostly the same', would just uncommenting Win 10 be all that's needed?

Comment: is the app.manifest added to the csproj? "<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>"

Answer (score 1):

You could get this from WMI instead.

```
Dim wmiOs As New ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem")
Dim version = wmiOs.GetInstances().Cast(Of ManagementObject).First.GetPropertyValue("Version")
```

Gives

```
10.0.14393
```